# how to upload a file in hue as a demo user

Tags: hive, hue

I was exploring the [hue platform](https://gethue.com/) for running basic hive queries. I wanted to upload a csv file from my local system to hue so that I can import that as a table. But I am not able to figure out any way. Google searches were resulting only for cloudera and other adaptations. But I am not sure whether it is possible to upload file from local to hue and if it is possible then what is the way.

Comment: On the left press Tables, in Table browser choose Hive, Press New to create new table, then Type->File, drag and drop file... Oops It does not work after upload... Consider using something else. For example databricks

Comment: Thanks for replying, yeah that's why I asked this question.

Comment: what my understanding is that we have to connect our hue with some instance of s3 bucket or with local hdfs somehow. please anyone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: https://demo.gethue.com/hue is very unstable and often does not work. Better use something else like databricks for studying. You said nothing about "our hue" and s3 bucket in the question... You better describe your current setup and what should be done exactly in the question rather than asking in the comments

Comment: actually I am quite new to this, while putting this question I was analyzing this and later on I came to know about the s3 thing. BTW, Thanks for your reply. Should I close this question incase moving to databricks is the only solution?

Comment: If you about  demo.gethue.com - yes, this is definitely not an option. databricks is not the only solution... You can insatall local hadoop with hive. Also you can try running it in a docker. You can use hive CLI instead of Hue